# How to create diamond pattern on object?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to make a pendant covered in diamonds and I can't figure out how to get the diamonds to go on the surface clean. I've tried shrink-wrap and the results are awful. The pendent base is complex, and the diamonds are pretty simple.

Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRKdx.png)

[image]

Comment: I recommend using a particle system instead, possibly remeshing the base mesh first and admitting one particle per vertex.